# How to run shiny in non-blocking way?

Tags: r, shiny

The method `runApp` would always run in blocking way even I specify `launch.browser=FALSE`, does anyone know how can run I run shiny App in non-blocking way ? Because after launching shiny app, I still want to execute R code in R session.

Comment: You'll have to open the app in another session as shown [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/running.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can run a shiny app from the terminal as a separate process.

```
R -e "shiny::runApp('~/shinyapp')"
```

`~/shinyapp` should be the directory of your app.

More info at RStudio's site:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/running.html